# How can i set the calender instance getTime value back to the date object?

Tags: java, file, date, calendar

First i have written the Calender instance getTime method value to a file. now by reading the file i want to set that value as date object?

Format of the data written to the file

> Wed Mar 29 18:54:53 IST 2017

How can i do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: See `SimpleDateFormat` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and please look in SO, there are many examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the the class SimpleDateFormat: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

This should work for your example:

```
String inputString = "Wed Mar 29 18:54:53 IST 2017";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf.parse(inputString)
```

Comment: Answering obviously duplicate Questions is not helpful.